# Why is magnesium sulfate acidic? Why are my calculations showing that it is basic?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, solubility, ph

Let's say I was dissolving $\pu{1 M}~\ce{MgSO4}$ into water and I wanted to find its $\mathrm{pH}$. I would go right to the reaction of the dissociation of $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$:

$$\ce{Mg(OH)2 <=> Mg^2+ + 2OH-}$$

The $K_\mathrm{sp}$ expression for this reaction is:

$$K_\mathrm{sp}=[\ce{Mg^2+}][\ce{OH-}]^2$$

According to wikipedia (see sources at bottom), the $K_\mathrm{sp}$ for $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ is $\pu{5.61*10^{-12}}$

$$\pu{5.61*10^{-12}}=[\ce{Mg^2+}][\ce{OH-}]^2$$

My molarity of $\ce{MgSO4}$ will be the same as that of $\ce{Mg^2+}$, which is $\pu{1 M}$. Substitute that in.

$$\pu{5.61*10^{-12}}=[\ce{OH-}]^2$$

And then solving for $[\ce{OH-}]$ we get:

$$[\ce{OH-}]=\pu{2.37*10^{-6} M}$$

Therefore:

$$\mathrm{pOH}=5.63$$
and
$$\mathrm{pH}=8.37$$

So my final solution of $\ce{MgSO4}$ will be basic. However, on stack exchange it says that the $\mathrm{pH}$ of $\ce{MgSO4}$ is between 5.5 and 6.5. The post does not explain why, but that the general consensus is that that is the range of the $\mathrm{pH}$.

What did I do wrong?

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_hydroxide

[Is magnesium sulfate basic, neutral or acidic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49825/is-magnesium-sulfate-basic-neutral-or-acidic)

Comment: Simplified calculations which result in pH values between 6-8 (usually from extremely dilute acid/base solutions or by addtion of very weak acid/bases to water) are generally incorrect because they fail to take into consideration the autodissociation of water. Pure water starts at pH 7, and any hydroxide ions consumed by $\ce{Mg^2+}$ *must* cause the pH to fall below 7, as you would expect from adding an acid. Multiple previous answers here at Chem.SE touch on this point, for example [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7838/1499). You will have to find a slightly different equation.

Comment: Using the Ksp of $\ce{Mg(OH)_2}$ would give you the *maximum* concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ for a solution of a given amount of $\ce{Mg^2+}$ - it won't necessarily give you the actual concentration. (It's perfectly happy with solubility products below the Ksp value.) -- If you're getting a pH above 7.0, you have to ask yourself where the "extra" $\ce{OH-}$ is coming from. It's from water, obviously, but what's driving the "extra" splitting of the $\ce{H2O}$, and - critically - what's happening to the $\ce{H+}$ that's being generated by the auto-dissociation of water to form the extra $\ce{OH-}$?

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49825/is-magnesium-sulfate-basic-neutral-or-acidic) for this question. The pH is depend on the concentration of $\ce{Mg^2+}$, thus why the range of pH is given.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer lies not in the solubility product but in the acidity constants of sulfuric acid and the basicity constants of $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$, though the solubility product may well come into play. You would need to solve a system of 6 equations, one for each of the:

- 2 $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values for the acid
- Two $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ values for the base
- Proton condition or charge neutrality
- And as you will be groping in $\mathrm{pH}$, one to be sure you don't exceed the solubility product.

As sulfuric acid is 'stronger' as an acid than $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ is as a base, you would expect the answer to be slightly on the "acid side" of neutral $\mathrm{pH}$.

Comment: Magnesium salts do, however, form less acidic solutions than those of most other metals.  It's an example of magnesium hydroxide being in a "gray zone" (like phosphoric acid among acids) between "strong" and "weak".

Answer (score 2):

Another aspect to be taken into account is the difference between measured solubility and solubility as calculated from the solubility product. Salts like $\ce{MgSO_4}$ are always much more soluble than what can be calculated from the solubility product. I don't have the numerical values for $\ce{MgSO_4}$, but I know the corresponding values for $\ce{CaSO_4}$, which is its neighbor in the periodic table. Calculated from $\ce{K_{sp}}$, the solubility is $4.7$ mM. The measured value, obtained by titration, is $18$ mM, as stated in J. Chem. Educ. $77, 12$, Dec. $2000$, p.$1558$

This discrepancy is due to hydrolysis. An important part of the $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ ions react with water to produce  ions like $\ce{[Ca(OH)]^{+}}$ according to the equation  $$\ce{Ca^{2+} + H_2O -> [Ca(OH)]^+  +  H^+}$$  $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ should react the same way.$$\ce{Mg^{2+} + H_2O -> [Mg(OH)]^+  +  H^+}$$  Simultaneously, an important part of the sulfate ions are reacting according to the following equation $$\ce{SO_4^{2-} + H_2O -> HSO_4^- + OH^-}$$ And there is also the possibility that some $\ce{CaSO_4}$ ou $\ce{MgSO_4}$ gets dissolved without being dissociated. The relative extent of these two last reactions is the reason why $\ce{MgSO_4}$ gives non neutral solutions in water.